# Maintaining log.django file

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have the standard django logging config in my `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'log.django',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}
```

so it logs to `log.django`. However `log.django` is getting too big (>500k lines) so I'm wondering if it is ok to delete this file. Will the file create itself once it's deleted?

I'm running django with nginx/gunicorn via digitalocean and I thought there was already a measure in place to maintain this file - but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Yes, the file will be created. logging.Filehandler uses the builtin function `open()` in mode `a` as a default. The logrotation/management facilities of your webserver (nginx) have nothing to do with the logging you use in your web application, i.e. your django app. You can implement logrotation based on log file size by using [logging.RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) instead of logging.FileHandler

Comment: Whoops, sorry ... logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler would be the correct path

Comment: How would I set the following: `filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False` in my `settings.py`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler

Comment: Or what will happen if I simply change it to: `'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler'`

Comment: Django uses standard python logging, so this is a vanilla dict config you go for. basically, yes, replace the class in your subdict `file` above and add a key-value pair for every argument you want to pass to the RotatingFileHandler upon instantiation.

Comment: Perfect it's working, thankyou!